# Array not updating values after function call

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need the array to have all the possible combinations of the `(x,y)` coordinates that I am generating. The array still prints as an array of `1`s.

```
import numpy as np

coordinates = np.ones([1000, 2])

def translate (x,y):
    dx = 5
    dy = 5
    return x + dx, y + dy

for i in range(0, 100):
    for j in range(0, 100):
        (x, y) = translate(i, j)
        coordinates[i, j] = translate(x, y)
        np.append(coordinates, translate(x, y), axis=None)

print(coordinates)
```

I expect coordinates array to receive the correct values after the `translate` function is called and not an array of `1`s.

Comment: your code gives me error `"ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."` because `translate` returns tuple but array expects single number.

Comment: there is other problem: you create array with size 1000x2 but later you use for loops like with array 100x100. This gives error `"IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2"`

Comment: Why are you calling `translate()` 3 times?

Comment: I was just trying out what could work

Comment: You didn't read `np.append` docs with enough care.  It's not a list clone.

Comment: I wasn't cloning anything

Comment: You were using `np.append` as though it acted in in-place like a `list.append` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all possible `(x,y)` coordinates that can be generated by varying `x=0..99` and `y=0..99` and then adding some `dx` and `dy` to `x` and `y`, respectively.

One approach, similar to yours, is to initialize an empty list, and then just append a tuple with the translation function you defined:

```
coordinates = []

def translate (x,y):
    dx = 5
    dy = 5
    return x + dx, y + dy

for x in range(0, 100):
    for y in range(0, 100):
        coordinates.append(translate(x,y))

print(coordinates)
```

However, this could be improved. Realize that you are simply adding `dx` to every `x` and `dy` to every `y`, so you can achieve the same result with simpler code by removing the `translate` function:

```
coordinates = []
dx, dy = 5, 5

for x in range(dx, 100+dx):
    for y in range(dy, 100+dy):
        coordinates.append((x,y))

print(coordinates)
```

Which will give you the same correct answer.

Comment: yes it works!! thank you. But why did my solution not work?

Comment: Three problems: First, the `translate` function returns a tuple with two values, but you were assigning the result of the function to `coordinates[i, j]` which is a single value. So, delete that line. Second, you are trying to append `translate(x,y)` instead of `translate(i,j)` in the call to `np.append`. Third, you are using `np.append` incorrectly, so nothing is being changed, and you are just returning the matrix of 1's that you initialized in the beginning.

Comment: thank you so much! I think I was using np.append correctly since I was using a numpy array and not a list though.

Comment: `np.append` does not function "in-place." In other words, it returns the result to a new variable. However, you were not assigning the result to anything, so it was lost. You would have needed something like `result = np.append(coordinates, translate(x, y))`. More information [in the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html).